# Creating PPT from two different excel file in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to open a excel file, take the ranges as picture and create a ppt our of it. I am not sure what is going wrong in the code below. Can someone help please? The code works well for all other slides coming from other excel file. The moment I opena  excel file and switch , it is throwing "subscript out of range error"

```
Sub GlobalBankPPT()
 Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
 Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
 Dim ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape
 Dim ppPic As Variant
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim wkb As Workbook
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim WS_Count As Integer, i As Integer
 Dim mypp As New ExcelToPPt.cPPt

 mypp.InitFromTemplate MyTemplateppt:=mytemp, MyOutputppt:=""

 Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
 ppApp.Visible = msoTrue
 Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation


Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range   ("FilePath"))
wkb.Activate

WS_Count = wkb.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To WS_Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Industry" Then
        wkb.Activate
        Set sh = ActiveSheet
        Exit For

 End If
Next I

'--------------------------------------------------------------------Slide7
 Range(Sheet15.Range("A150"), Sheet15.Range("Q191")).Select
 Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
 ppPres.Slides(7).Select
 Set ppPic = ppPres.Slides(7).Shapes.Paste

 ppPic.Select
 ppPic.Top = 70.24
 ppPic.Width = 10.5 * 100
 ppPic.Height = ppPic.Width / 3.4
 ppPic.Left = 50

end sub
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error if you press `debug` button?

Comment: The line after Slide 7 comment